# In Python, can I make a code thread safe, if I'm using a C extension that is not?

Tags: python, thread-safety

My Python code have strange bugs, and I wonder if it could be caused by using a thread unsafe C extension.
Would it be possible to use some Python features, like "lock", to fix that C extension problem? And how could I implement this?

[edit 1]
Here's what my code looks like:

```
import CextensionPackage as cext

try:
    (output) = cext.extension_function(inputs)
except:
    pass
```

[edit 3]
The package **init**.py file looks like:

```
from c_ext import functionx

def extension_function( ... )
    ...
    outputs = functionx( ... )
```

Then the C extension c_ext.c looks like:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <cext.h>
static PyObject *functionx(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
char *string;
int stringsize;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#", &string, &stringsize))
    return NULL;
outputs = thread_unsafe_C_function(string);
```

[edit 2]
Basically, I would like to force cext.extension_function, or the thread_unsafe_C_function (and all the functions it calls in the C extension library) to execute on a single thread. I think that would solve my problem, but how can I do that?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. What makes you believe the C extension is causing the problems? Without any kind of code to look at, it will be hard to help you. I suppose you could wrap all the C extension calls inside a class which you've made thread-safe, but I'd run down the possibility that it's my own code first.

Comment: I know the C extension I'm using is tread unsafe, because there's a clear warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you think your C extension is not thread-safe, then you can use Python synchronization primitives (like a lock) to ensure that only one thread is executing in the extension at a time.  There's no way for me to know if that will help you with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the c extension code does something stupid, I don't think you have any choice but to choose to use it or not.  Only exception would be if you have access to the code and can make sure it does what you want.

The c code could release the GIL inappropriately, or create its own threads internally.

Can you do anything to make sure the problem don't exist without the extension (make sure the bug isn't on your side)?  Maybe more explanation of the question would help, but if I didn't trust an extension, I just wouldn't use it.  I don't think you can force it to do what you want without source.

[edit]We need to see more of the code.  What happens to the outputs parameter?  Also, how are you creating additional threads?

Comment: I have the C source code, I agree the proper solution would be to fix the C code. But I was wondering it I could use the GIL features from Python instead, as a workaround.